# how to correct this problem $ printenv | grep ROS $: command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when,i am installing kinetic

```
$  printenv | grep ROS
$: command not found
```

it is showing how to rectify this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341008/how-to-correct-this-problem-%7B9ee508e6-8443-459f-ae95-9d5714039bc5%7D:-command-not-found/) by [hari](https://answers.ros.org/users/50670/hari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try env | grep -i ROS

---

Originally posted by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) with karma: 195 on 2020-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0